# Uber Driver is crashing (not even start) on Android 8.1

Tags: crashes, 8.1-oreo, uber

I bought a new phone because my older was so old that Uber Driver was too slow, couldn't even use a different map service (like Google Maps or Waze). Bought a Redmi 6 (International Version), with Android 8.1.0 and MIUI Global 10.0.

So I installed Uber Driver, and to my surprise it crashed every time after the second screen of "what's new". I uninstalled it, and now after some two months I tried again. The problem persists. The first screens with instructions worked fine the first time (though the loud voice can't be turned off or lowered -- and the device volume is muted!). After these screens, came the "what's new" screens, and it crashed in the second. Now it just crashes before these screens, every time I try to open the app. The system is up to date. What can I do?

EDIT

Following @trishmapow comments, I managed to use `adb logcat` to create a log. The log file has 540 kB, and registered every information since the device was last turned on (I thought it would only register from the moment the command was issued). Should I upload this whole log somewhere? Should I extract only lines with some word in them?

Comment: Please share output of [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat).

Comment: This question might be better directed at the development team of the app... They'll have a much quicker solution than possibly modifying your device for compatibility.... Even if you change some settings ( most likely manually enabling permissions for the app in settings ) and everything works, I'm certain that such a large company would like to know of incompatibility problems especially a full crash, It'd be extremely helpful for them to supply the logcat and your specific device model... They can't test an app on every device in the world, so it'd be great to help them out with your test.

Comment: @trishmapow Thank you, I'm trying. No success yet, though.

Comment: @Zillinium I've sent an email to the address given [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubercab.driver&hl=en_US). Soon after I got the reply "We're sorry. You’ve contacted an address that does not accept incoming email (...) Please submit your request by tapping “Help” in the Uber app [impossible!] or by visiting help.uber.com from a web browser. There you’ll find answers to frequently asked questions **and have the option to submit a support request**." This last option, however, is nowhere to be seen. Great, huh? I'll try calling them tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to enable the permissions using the system app ? ... I've seen many apps crash on 8.1 because of the way it handles permissions, usually the developer needs to implement the new permission system to ask for permission acceptance... If it's designed for or targeted toward older model 5.1 for example, it doesn't need to ask for permission acceptance.... The workaround is to manually enable the permissions using the settings app, then try opening it again ( sometimes clear data and then reopen it ) ... My guess is that after the What's New screen, the app is requesting GPS Perm's

Comment: 1) The Setting you seek is probably under *About the phone* and *then* "System" (one step missing in that guide). 2) Thought about reporting that to the developers? They are much more likely able to help you than we are. 3) I second what @Zillinium just wrote: Had another app crashing a while ago because some access was not granted. So also check if you use some other protection app (like XPrivacyLua in my case). The guess with location permission sounds reasonable (and if it's that, the devs were sloppy and forgot to handle that exception).

Comment: @Izzy There's no "System" in mine. There's only "System update". I'll try the permissions thing, thank you both.

Comment: @Rodrigo look for something along the lines, like "Software information".

Comment: @Izzy On Redmi it's `MIUI Version`, not `Build number`.

Comment: Right! Just wanted to correct that (was answered on another question today). So glad you found it already yourself! Those manufacturer-specific adjustments make it really hard to help people (similar issues with Samsung)…

Comment: @Izzy Log created, now what? Please see my last edit. I'm also in contact with the developers.

Comment: Huh? It was @trishmapow who asked for it. I just chimed in for enabling USB debugging :) But I'd say put it on some pastebin and then [edit] your question with a link to it. You might wish to check the log yourself before that and "sanitize" it (replace personal details).

Comment: @Izzy Yes sure. But 4k+ lines? I wouldn't know what should I remove from them. Btw, Uber answered "we're working on the problem", though there's at least two months the problem exists, and they totally ignored when I said (three times!) I had a log. I think I'll just give up from Uber...

Comment: If they already admitted to know the problem, that it's theirs and they need to work to fix it, I guess you've got to wait for their update. Afraid there's nothing we can do to make it compatible.